# Execute function only when element is not focused

Tags: javascript, html, function, select, element

There's a script running on my website but I want it to be executed only when certain element is NOT focused. Here's my general idea how it'd look

```
window.setInterval(function(){
   if (document.getElementById('someElement') != focused) {
   doSomething;
   }
}, 1000);
```

The "someElement" is set to be editable so it can be clicked (focused).

My question is how would "!= focused" look in javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `document.activeElement`

like this

```
if (document.getElementById('someElement') !== document.activeElement)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to check focus.............

```
window.setInterval(function(){
   if (document.getElementById('someElement').is(":focus") {
   doSomething;
   }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: its only working with jquery